# SQL Server Agent Job custom error message

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I have created a step (Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)), which contains this query:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SalarySum >= 10000 THEN 1 
    ELSE 1 / 0 END AS result 
FROM dbo.salary
```

This query works, but I think that is bad way to stop SQL Agent Job to error message: "Divide by zero error encountered."
What is "correct" way to stop SQL Agent Job in this case, if there is an error?
ELSE ...

New example:

```
WITH TEST_CTE
AS
(
SELECT * FROM dbo.salary
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dbo.salary2
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SalarySum >= 10000 THEN 1 
    ELSE 1 / 0 END AS result 
FROM TEST_CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like....

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM dbo.salary
           WHERE SalarySum < 10000)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Salary Sum is less than 10000' , 16 ,1)
END
```

Or maybe put this into a stored procedure and call that proc from the SQL Agent job.

Comment: Thank you! One question more: What about if I'm using CTE. I add new example code.